# phpmyadmin combine text and column in SET SQL

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to use the existing values in columns to create a new column using phpmyadmin.

I currently have the following database.

```
| First_Name | Second_Name    | Full_Name |
| ---------- | -------------- | --------- |
| Paul       | Smith          |           |
| Mike       | Wazowski       |           |

...
```

I have first names and second names, but I'm wanting to insert data into full name with some text. I have used this command below to insert data:

```
UPDATE `users` SET `Full _Name`='some text' + `First_Name`;
```

However that returns the problem `Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work:

```
UPDATE users SET Full_Name = CONCAT(First_Name," ",Second_name)
```

https://www.w3schools.com/Sql/func_mysql_concat.asp